# Align a figure with subfigures in a Float

Tags: graphics, positioning, subfloats, ieeetran, scaling

I am using IEEEtrans.cls to create two column IEEE article. I wanted to place an image in one large figure in first column and the other four smaller subfigures in the second column aligned to the first figure. Using the subfig package I wrote the following code.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,compsoc,journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[tbhp] 
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.7,width=.49\textwidth]{motivation01.pdf}
}\hfill
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.2\textwidth]{Freescale1.pdf}
}\hfill \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.366,width=.2\textwidth]{Transport.pdf}
}\\
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.366]{nd24k.pdf}
}\hfill \subfloat[]{\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{tube1.pdf}
}
\caption{Sparsity Structure of some sparse matrices}
\label{freq} \end{figure*} 

\end{document}
```

But I get the following output:

[image: Output Image]

We can observe that the subfigures are not aligned, I want subfigure(b) and (c) to align with (a) on top and subfigures (d) and (e) should align with (a) on the bottom. What would be the best possible way to attain this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use separate `minipage` environments for the first subfloat and the remaining subfloats. Set the width of each `minipage` to `\columnwidth`. Inside the right-hand `minipage`, choose the widths of the graphs suitably to meet your design needs; I chose `0.475\linewidth`; you should treat this choice just as a starting point.

[image]

```
\documentclass[twocolumn,compsoc,journal,demo]{IEEEtran} % remove 'demo' option in real doc.
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[caption=false,font=normalsize,
            labelfont=sf,textfont=sf]{subfig}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure*} 
\begin{minipage}[b]{\columnwidth}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,height=\columnwidth]{motivation01.pdf}}
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[b]{\columnwidth}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.475\linewidth]{Freescale1.pdf}}
\hfill 
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.475\linewidth]{Transport.pdf}}

\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.475\linewidth]{nd24k.pdf}}
\hfill 
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.475\linewidth]{tube1.pdf}}
\end{minipage}
\caption{Sparsity Structure of some sparse matrices}
\label{freq} 
\end{figure*} 

\end{document}
```